# Weka: Batch filtering command is showing error: Input file format differ, using MAC OS X

Tags: java, weka, svm, libsvm

I have been trying to run one simple example to check Weka GUI interface as I am planning to develop Support Vector Machine(SVM) using Weka API/WLSVM in my Java code. There are three steps I am following to make arff from text datasets (Training & Testing). You can assistant me to run it in Java code.

1. text file to .arff file converter.
2. Applied StringToWordVector Filter.
3. Applied Batch Filter on training and test datasets.

---

### 1. text file to .arff file converter.

This step works fine on Simple CLI using following command

> Error: java weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader -dir Testing_Text > Testing.arff

but when I run it on MAC bash it gives following error, how can I resolve this issue?

> Could not find or load main class weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader

---

### 2. Applied StringToWordVector Filter

I applied this filter using Weka GUI Interface separately first training and then on testing datasets.

---

### 3. Applied Batch Filter on training and testing dataset.

When I try to apply batch filter it gives *error: Input file formats differ* on Simple CLI using following command.

> java weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Standardize -b -i Training_STWV.arff -o train_std.arff -r TestingDiff_STWV.arff -s test_std.arff

Input file formats differ.

Kindly guide me, I am stuck to run Support Vector Machine(SVM) classifier using Weka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard procedure on the Mac is, to change into the directory (e.g. `weka-3.6.8/`) and run

```
java -Xmx1000M -jar weka.jar
```

Check if that works.

If it does, check that in your own example, you have the classpath properly set (`-jar weka.jar`).

Answer (score 1):

Batch Filtering command (-b) is working now with following command.

```
java weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector -b -i Training.arff -o train_std.arff -r Testing.arff -s test_std.arff
```